# Text breaking out of Divs - only in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I hope I do not break any rules of this website but posting a link to the issue is a necessity. I have copied the html from the source and tested in a local html file and it does not break. I can not work this out for the life of me.

If you look at the demo web page you can see where the text breaks throughout the whole site (it is a wordpress site if that helps).

[Online Demo](http://kenyaaustraliamission.com/international-strategy/)

Here is the html:

```
<h2>Our Core Values:</h2>
<strong>Relationship with God: </strong> This is our primary relationship.  We were created to serve and give praise to our Creator, through our thoughts, words, and actions.  When we do this, we experience the presence of God as our Heavenly Father and live in a joyful, intimate relationship with Him.

<strong>Relationship with Self:</strong> People are uniquely created in the image of God and thus have inherent worth and dignity.  While we must remember that we are not God, we have the high calling of reflecting God’s being, making us superior to the rest of creation.

<strong>Relationship with Others:</strong> God created us to live in loving relationship with one another, and to encourage one another to use the gifts God has given to each of us to fulfill our calling.

<strong>Relationship with the rest of Creation:</strong> The cultural mandate of Gen 1:28-30 teaches that God created us to be stewards, people who understand, subdue and manage the world that God created in order to produce bounty.  While God made the World ‘perfect’ He left it incomplete.  God called humans to interact with creation to make possibilities into realities and to be able to sustain ourselves via the fruit of our stewardship.  The economically poor are singled out in the Scriptures as being in a particularly desperate category and as needing very specific attention (Acts :-1:6-7)
<ul>
<li>Faith – God is our provider and equips in all He calls us to do.</li>
<li>The Great Commissions -  We are called to make disciples of all nations (Matthew 28:19-20)</li>
<li>Relationship - The body of Christ is held together in relationship with the Lord and each other and self.</li>
<li>Partnership – The Lord never calls one person to work alone.  A biblical, effective model of missionary involvement.  Ministry partnerships should promote interdependence, not dependence.</li>
<li>Leadership – The five-fold gifts are meant to operate in the establishment and leading of the church.</li>
<li>Faithful stewardship and accountability are essential for successful ministry.</li>
```

Like I said this works fine if you copy the source into a local html page and test using WAMP.

Please I hope someone can help me with this and again if posting a link is against the rules I am sorry but as the issue is localised to this one instance I have no other choice.

Comment: Hi! I can't see any text break in your site. Can you add one screenshot to your question.

Comment: You mean this page right ? http://kenyaaustraliamission.com/statement-of-faith/

Comment: No I mean that your linked page. Okay! I can see lot of issues. Wait

Comment: @Mindeater Just use in your css file. `.row {word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify;}`. That's it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS

```css
li { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Comment: To make you answer more useful can you explain why your suggestion solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your page http://kenyaaustraliamission.com/statement-of-faith/

is breaking out of the container because the spaces in the text are replaced with non-breaking space entity references

check the actual text in your WordPress Dashboard

```
    We&nbsp;believe&nbsp;the&nbsp;Bible&nbsp;to&nbsp;be&nbsp;the&nbsp;inspired,&nbsp;only,&nbsp;infallible&nbsp;and&nbsp;authoritative&nbsp;Word&nbsp;of&nbsp;God
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html problem please remove in **p** `tag` `&nbsp;`  in your html code

Example is below

[image]

Now check to **[this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/remove-empty-lines-nbsp-when-author-updates-their-post)**

Comment: for wordpress those p tag r added automatically, when u create post. don't think that it can be removed

Comment: @cjmling now to this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/remove-empty-lines-nbsp-when-author-updates-their-post

Comment: @RohitAzad I agree with cjmling. You have to give a simple quick solution before you go big one. So, I suppose the answer is `.row {word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify;}` to add in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Your page is http://kenyaaustraliamission.com/statement-of-faith/ is breaking because its taking whole line as a single word and going out of div. This is due to non breaking space in each space.